# How to change drive letter in Win 7 dual HD mSata and regular

Tags: windows-7, drive-letter, msata

I have just added a new mSata HD to my computer and I am unable to change the drive letter. This is a latop/notebook running Windows 7 SP1.

I have tried the traditional method right click my computer > manage > computer management > disk management which generates an error Invalid Parameter.

I have Ubutu installed on the old harddisk as well so tried to boot with than and using Gpart tried to change the drive letters as well however in Linux there is no use of drive letter and hence there is no option for sucj activities.

Here is the specs:

500GB hard disk 3 partitions
C: windows 7
d: Ubuntu
e: data

Now new mSata added
f: mSata windows 7

want to make f the new c drive and the old drive h drive and format it.

there are some advise on the net to make changes to the registry which messed my computer up and I had to run recovery.

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: So you want to clone the old drive to the new one? Or just change the drive letters? Windows won't like now being on C:\ at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not getting what exactly you want to do. What I understand is that you want to use both HDDs and want to install win 7 in only new HDD (mSata HD) and remove old win 7. If you want so then,

- Just boot into **WIN 7 which is installed in New HDD (mSata HD)**. There you can format old win 7 drive. You can also use other third party partition manager tools to format old win 7 drive because sometimes win give error while formatting such drives.
- Now after formatting old drive just reboot win 7 (New HDD) and you will get C: back.

**Note:**

- Win 7 assigns drive letters according to availability of letters and each OS has it's own drive assignment (i.e. Both OS can have c drive letter assigned to their respective root drives.)**.**